# Write to file completely forgoing server-side scripting?

Tags: javascript, file-io

A short while ago, I decided to do a cleaning roster for our flat share. Being the lazy bastards that we are, I hacked together a semi-automated one with standard *HTML5/JavaScript* and plan to make it mandatory for all of us to have it set as home page. Basically I'm displaying an SVG floorplan where the rooms are colour-coded according to how long certain tasks have been neglected. Naturally users will be able to update both task preferences and status.

Now that I'm nearly finished, the only thing missing is *overwriting the JSON file (located in the same directory as the HTML/JS) with the updated data*. And that's where my troubles lie.

You see, the roster will be stored on and hence accessed from a hard drive plugged into our router's USB port via NetBIOS/SMB. So I have *no access to server-side scripting* as there won't be a server involved. Neither do I have a fixed browser or even OS.

**Is this at all possible** or should I just ditch that thing and use Python?

Thanks in advance. :-)

*TL;DR: just skim through for the italic parts*

Comment: Are people accessing the page through the router url via http, or a mapped file://?

Comment: This is awesome, and I want to see how it turns out.

Comment: The router has an embedded NetBIOS/SMB server, so the access method will be similar to the file protocol (caveat: I've never dabbled in SMB, so this is no more than an educated guess). Will edit the post to clarify.

Comment: Have you considered simply hosting on github pages so you can have said 'fixed browser / OS'?  Otherwise, your question seems to be asking how to access your router's hard drive with standard HTML5/JavaScript.

Comment: @Sze-HungDanielTsui To be honest, I would prefer that no actual data about how we go about our cleaning leave the flat share's network (not going into details, let's just say it's a bit of a delicate issue for us). Otherwise I'd probably put the whole thing on my webspace where I could just use PHP.

Comment: That's fair. It's an interesting problem to tackle, purely in JS/HTML. I hope you find a solution. I hope you share it too! Good luck.

Comment: You could also install Apache and PHP somewhere locally on your network...there are packages that make it easy to set up on Windows, Mac, and Linux. You can also run PHP on IIS.

Comment: And of course that would only be needed for the file saving part...you could leave the rest of your code as is.

Comment: To boil it down: you will need some shared state. Saving client-side won't help you. To save server-side the server needs to support write requests in some form or another. Your server does not support any sort of writing. Hence: not really.

Comment: As an alternative, if you really want to avoid the cleaning, why not implement a distributed database using local storage and interconnected with WebRTC ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/Peer-to-peer_communications_with_WebRTC

Comment: @MattBrowne We don't have a server in our flat share, the hard drive is plugged directly into our router which has SMB functionality. Setting up a server would in our case involve literally setting up another machine, which does seem overkill.

Comment: I think that if security is important, @Adam's suggestion may be your best option. The only other alternatives I know of are setting up a local server or saving the file to a remote server...and if you use a remote server then you'd need to prompt the user for authentication credentials in order for it to be secure (obviously you wouldn't want to put the username and password in your JS file).

Comment: Thinking outside the box...I saw a Chromebox on sale for $150. I'm not sure if it has the capability to run a server, but if not I think you can install Linux on it instead...probably more expense and trouble than it's worth, but I thought this was worth mentioning at least.

Comment: @MattBrowne Definitely worth mentioning, although shipping costs (to Germany) would probably balance out the amount I'd save. :-)

Comment: You mentioned using Python...did you mean a Python desktop app? If so, rather than having to rewrite your app, you could use this framework: http://www.tidesdk.org/ ...which lets you write desktop apps using HTML5 but still be able to interact with the OS.

Comment: @MattBrowne Indeed I did. Main point of doing it browser-based was we all use browsers everyday, and having the cleaning roster as mandatory home page we couldn't overlook tasks even on tight-scheduled days. If that isn't possible with the infrastructure I have, I'll have to decide if I want to do it server-based or write a desktop app. I haven't lost all hope yet (my current best bet is looking for an SMB framework for JavaScript), but if I do find out my plan isn't possible to realise, I'll post or link the unfinished code in case someone can make use of it. Tide SDK looks promising, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible across all the most recent browsers by using the `Blob` object or data URIs. For older versions of IE, since you are only saving a text file (the JSON file) you are in luck: there's a library for saving files using Blobs or data URIs that also has a fallback for IE:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#ie--10

FYI, if you needed to save something other than a text file, you would have to do this with a plugin like Flash or Java. Here's a library that does that:
https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

And here's a good overview of the various options for client-side file generation and download:
http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2011/07/04/javascript-client-side-file-generation-and-download/

Also FYI, here's a library for generating zip files on the client-side:
http://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: Who is downvoting and why?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe someone other than OP?

Comment: I can think of two options. 1. It sounds like they need to update the contents of, or outright replace, an existing JSON file *automatically*. The tools you've linked to seem to just provide a file for download, so the user would have to save it over the existing file manually (that might be a compromise they're willing to make). 2. This essentially boils down to a link-only answer where you say use this plug-in, but don't explain why it solves their problem or how it would be used to do so.

Comment: @MattBrowne I haven't downvoted anything, but Anthony is correct in that I would replace the JSON file rather than providing it for download. Pity, apart from that it would have been perfect.

Comment: Any possibility of storing the file or data in the cloud? In that case you could use Firebase as @Sze-Hung suggested or any number of other cloud options...

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking for would require the browser to make assumptions about the user's file system and be able to save files to an arbitrary location (without the user's input) that might not even exist on the user's machine. It's possible to trigger the download script I mentioned via Javascript, but the user would still have to browse for the location where the file should be saved.

Comment: The JSON file is actually in the same directory as the roster HTML. The whole thing is on an NTFS partition on a USB drive which is accessed via the router's SMB. This much I know. The respective clients however are on both Windows and Linux machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Firebase, purely client-side!

There are [few](https://github.com/firebase/firechat) 
[CRUD examples](http://runnable.com/UnA1eTROpKNmAABE/firebase-chat-example-for-javascript) [out there](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/back-end-with-firebase.html). (That last one is Angular.)

Since your data is in JSON, the first place I'd start is the part of their tutorial that writes to [objects](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#tutorial/basic/3).

Comment: To clarify: If you have your app's state stored in JSON, I'd find a way to convert that and save it in Firebase. It's pretty painless. When you modify the stored object the JSON will be updated automatically.

Comment: JSON isn't mandatory, I just decided I'd give it a try for the sake of experience (and I've grown a bit tired of XML).While Firebase seems like it would not only solve my problem, but also prevent others that I haven't even begun to tackle, I would prefer the data staying local. If I understood correctly, Firebase doesn't have that option?

Comment: To my knowledge, Firebase doesn't have that option.